# In SQL, how would you return the String values of a column where the Strings returned are between the starting letters 'a' to 'm'?

Tags: sql, string, oracle, where-clause

I've tried using the LIKE operator as well as the BETWEEN operator and both together but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

One option uses a regex:

```
where regexp_like(mycol, '^[a-m]')
```

You can make the condition case insensitive so it allows `A-M` as well with match parameter `'i'`:

```
where regexp_like(mycol, '^[a-m]', 'i')
```

Comment: This also solved it. Regex is a new one for me so thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

I would write:

```
where str >= 'a' and str < 'n'
```

Comment: This did it. I wasn't aware you could use comparison operators to return String values based off the beginning characters. Thanks.

Comment: @JamesSerenity . . . This can also use an index.  However, it is unlikely that one would be useful for such a broad range of strings.